# SOLVED - How to attach a class to dynamically loaded images

Tags: jquery, class, binding

I will try to describe my problem but consider that I could use the wrong terms due to my English knowledge.

In a WEB page, I'm creating a list of objects with records downloaded from a MySQL DB. Among the fields, there is one for an image that I show in the record row as a thumbnail.

I'm using **magnificPopup** to get a real size (and description) of all the images  with a defined class (.popup), like this:

```
$('.popup').magnificPopup({
      type: 'image',
      closeOnContentClick: 'true'
});
```

When I click on a static image (coded into the HTML) everything is ok, like this:

```
<a class="popup" id="linkImg" href="img/chip.jpg" title="some text">
  <img id="imagine" src="img/chip.jpg" class="imagineCls">
</a>
```

For the loaded images this does not work and clicking on the image shows a new page and I have to press Back on the browser to return, thus reloading the page and downloading again all the records.

It is evident that the jQuery function is not activated for the '.popup' class and is not found on the page

The JS function that creates the list has a row like this:

```
s += "<li class='liVoice'><a class='popup' href='Pics/"+list['Pic']+"'><img class='thumb' src='Pics/"+list['Pic']+"' /></a></li>"
```

I remember that times ago I found a solution which was, in my terms, to bind (??) the wanted class to all the downloaded records at the end of the load, and it worked.

Unfortunately, I do not find any of those posts, possibly due to my search with the wrong terms too.

**EDIT**:
I found the solution with an extended research and digging deeply in my memory.
At the end it was quite simple: I added the call to magnificPopup in the function which loads and create the list at the end of the loop:

```
---- 
code that load the records
----
// end of records load

// added function call
$('.popup').magnificPopup({
  type: 'image',
  closeOnContentClick: 'true'
  });
} // end of function
```